# Silex + HttpCacheServiceProvider: X-Symfony-Cache is always miss

Tags: php, caching, silex, http-caching

I am just inserting the http cache on my silex project doing this:

```
// http cache
$this->register(new \Silex\Provider\HttpCacheServiceProvider(), array(
    'http_cache.cache_dir' => $this->getConfig()['http_cache_service']['cache_dir'],
));
```

$this is an owner class that it extends from Silex Application.

And my routing is:

```
    // homepage
    $this->get('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
        return new Response($app['twig']->render('index/index.html.twig', []), 200, [
            'Cache-Control' => 's-maxage=500'
        ]);
    })->bind('homepage');
```

And I run my application in this mode:

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1','localhost','192.168.2.11'));
$app['http_cache']->run();
```

I am following the steps written in http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/http_cache.html

But, when I load the 'homepage' the **X-Symfony-Cache** is always **miss**.

[image]

I am using Apache2 with PHP7, and I don't have installed any inversed proxy as Varnish, because I understand that it is not mandatory because HttpCacheServiceProvider is enough by itself.